# Copiar al portapapeles (Kotlin, Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Alguien me puede explicar cual es la forma mas sencilla de copiar un String o una variable String al portapapeles de android??

He probado el siguiente código pero me da error:

```
            val clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
            val clip: ClipData = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", "Hello, World!")
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
```

Y con las siguientes importaciones:

```
            import android.content.ClipData
            import android.content.ClipboardManager
            import android.content.Context
```

Este es el error que me da:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la consola:
Type inference failed: fun <T : Any!> getSystemService(p0: Context, p1: Class<T!>): T?
cannot be applied to
(String)

¿que me falta? que tengo mal?
gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el contexto, estas son 3 formas de usar el contexto para el método `getSystemService()` :

• Si te encuentras dentro de una activity esto es correcto:

```
val clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
```

• Si te encuentras dentro de un `Fragment` debes usar como contexto la `Activity` que contiene el Fragment usando `activity` :

```
val clipboard = activity.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
```

Revisa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646508/kotlin-android-copy-to-clipboard-from-fragment

• Si tu método se encuentra en otra clase debes enviar el contexto, por ejemplo esta clase contiene un método pero necesita el contexto el cual será enviado como un parámetro :

```
import android.content.ClipData
import android.content.ClipboardManager
import android.content.Context

class MyClass() {

     fun getClipboard(context: Context) {
        val clipboard = context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        val clip: ClipData = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", "Hola Stackoverflow.com")
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
    }

}
```

de esta forma instancias la clase y envías el contexto como parámetro desde tu Activity:

```
val myClass =  MyClass()
myClass.getClipboard(this)
```